# Return a number of matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a number of matches since it matches two. Right now I am just getting one from console.log().

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var page = 
'<tr class="Row">' +
    '<td class="1"><p>12/31/2010</p></td>'+
    '<td class="2">'+
                '<p>text</p>'+
    '</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'<tr class="Row">' +
    '<td class="1"><p>12/01/2009</p></td>'+
    '<td class="2">'+
                '<p>text</p>'+
    '</td>'+
'</tr>'
;

var pattern = /<td class="1"><p>((\d){2}(?=\/)\/(\d){2}(?=\/)\/20(\d){2})<\/p><\/td>/;
var match = page.match(pattern);  
console.log(page);
console.log(match);

</script>
```

Is there a way to retrieve all the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use `.exec()` for Regex in JavaScript with the `g` modifier at the end of the pattern. You can then iterate over the matches by calling this multiple times until `match` is null:

```
var pattern = /<td class="1"><p>((\d){2}(?=\/)\/(\d){2}(?=\/)\/20(\d){2})<\/p><\/td>/g;
var match = pattern.exec(page);  
console.log(page);

while(match){
   console.log(match);
   match = pattern.exec(page);
}
```

See this working: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/EtpQp/

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

just use the options.

```
pattern = /.../gm;
```

Comment: There's a problem with that. It removes the match[1]. Which should have been the date 12/31/2010.